# SQL Server : the partition scheme cannot be changed because there exists one or more incremental statistics on the table

Tags: sql-server, partition, database-partitioning, columnstore

I get this error and I cannot find solution for it

> The partition scheme cannot be changed because there exists one or more incremental statistics on the table

The background:

- SQL Server 2017
- I have a clustered columnstore index, partitioned by product
- I try to change to different partition scheme (by time)

Steps taken:

1. I drop the columnstore index
2. Try to build a regular clustered index on a new partition scheme
3. After this build (`drop_existing`) columnstore index with the new partition scheme

On the second step, I get the error mentioned.

Thank you

Yuri